# Dart String Iterable interface

Tags: string, dart, iteration, iterable

Why doesn't Dart String class implement the iterable interface? It seems like there is an obvious notion of iteration for strings, i.e. just return each character in turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not that terse as you would like

```dart
String s = 'foo';
s.codeUnits.forEach((f) => print(new String.fromCharCode(f)));
s.runes.forEach((f) => print(new String.fromCharCode(f)));
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer the "Why":

The `Iterable` interface is a fairly heavy-weight interface (many members) that is intended for collections of elements.

While a `String` can be seen as a `List` of characters (but Dart doesn't have a type for characters, so it would really be "List of single-character Strings"), that is not its main usage, and also being an `Iterable` would clutter the actual String methods.

A better solution would be to have a `List` *view* of a `String`. That is fairly easily doable:

```dart
class StringListView extends ListBase<String> {
  final String _string;
  StringListView(this._string);

  @override
  String operator [](int index) => _string[index];

  @override
  int get length => _string.length;

  @override
  set length(int newLength) {
    throw UnsupportedError("Unmodifiable");
  }

  @override
  void operator []=(int index, String v) {
    throw UnsupportedError("Unmodifiable");
  }
}
```

Would be even easier if the libraries exposed the `UnmodifiableListBase` used to make `UnmodifiableListView`.

Comment: I updated the code to remove the linter warnings, but I might have omitted a mixin because the original version had what appeared to be a dangling `with`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert Dart to `List` by using `.split('')` and you can use it as `Iterable`, because `List` is a subclass.

```dart
String s = 'foo';
for(String d in s.split('')) {
 print(d);
}
```